# Storing complete list values in SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to store the complete list data in SQL Server database table but I'm unable to do that...

```
for(int i=0;i<=mylist.Count;i++)
{
    string sql2 = "INSERT INTO data (channel_value) VALUES ( mylist[i])";
    SqlCommand abxb = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
    abxb.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Not surprising as you aren't actually putting the value of `mylist[i]` into your query string.

Comment: Your trying to store the string "mylist[i]" in your table with your code. You need to break up your string. '"INSERT INTO data (channel_value) VALUES (" + mylist[i] + ")"'  (<--Just a rough suggestion, may need more quotes in places)

Comment: Also, change the condition of your for loop to `i < mylist.Count`.

Comment: `string sql2 = String.Format("INSERT INTO data (channel_value) VALUES ( '{0}')",mylist[i]);`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass `mylist[i]` to your SQL string like that. Add a parameter to your `SqlCommand`, and set its value in a loop, like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO data (channel_value) VALUES (@val)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@val", SqlDbType.Int); // Pick the correct type here
foreach (var v in mylist) {
    cmd.Parameters["@val"].Value = v;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

A few things to note:

- In my SQL string I replaced `mylist[i]` with a named parameter `@val`
- Inside the loop I set `@val` to the value `mylist`, and call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`
- I used `foreach` instead of `for` because the index is not necessary inside the loop, and because you used `<=` instead of `<` for the condition on the list index.

Comment: Even better would be to create a proc with a table valued parameter and pass the whole set at once instead of hitting sql over and over.